# redis custom command in python

Tags: python, redis, geospatial

I'm executing a custom reis command in my python program. I want my result to be limited upto 50 but COUNT property for GEORADIS_RO is not working

```
result = c.execute_command('GEORADIUS_RO', redishset, longitude, 
latitude, int(radius)+int(increasedradius), 
'm',withdist=True,withcoord=True, 
withhash=False,sort='ASC',any=False,COUNT=50)
```